# Can I generate incremental Build Name in an OpenShift Origin build?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am building a image using a BuildConfig, in every build a new image with the tag latest is created because I am using this config

```
"output": {
 "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "myImage:latest"
   }
}
```

Is it possible to create images with a tag incremental? something like:

```
"output": {
 "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "myImage:${buildNumber}"
   }
}
```

if not, what is the best approach to build new images and store the versions in the openshift registry?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement, and I used environment variables passed to the build config.

```
"output": {
 "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "myImage:${buildNumber}"
   }
}


oc start-build buildconfig_name --env=buildnumber=value
```

Comment: But how do you get the build number? Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Are you sure this does what you say? Normally parameterisation only works when initially creating a set of resources from a template, and that is using separate concept of template parameters. Environment variables aren't used in parameterisation of resource object definitions when used.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton do you know how to build images with a build number autogenerated?

Comment: Rather than comment on what you believe is the solution, what is the actual use case you are trying to find a solution for? If have better idea of what you need it for, then can perhaps point you in the right direction.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thanks for your time. I want to implement a semantic versioning in every build so every time when a new commit appears, the build should run and create a new image.
For example we have the version 2.0.x. Where x should be the number of the build who built the image (This number is should be take it from Openshift, in the console you can find the number of the last build).
 
Using it you can have a image for every commit versioned and then you can use the version that you want.

Comment: Usually that would be handled through manually using your own tags in an image stream. As far as an automated way of handling build/deploy version you might also consider looking at pipelines. You can then specify the script as part of the Jenkins build to do that sort of thing.

Comment: for binary build it shows below error  "WARNING: Specifying environment variables with binary builds is not supported."

Comment: @Álvaro Pérez Soria your provided suggestion not working for binary build, i am getting warnings any suggestion for that?

Comment: Hey, it doesn't seem to work. Anything else you do besides writing `"myImage:${buildNumber}"` in buildconfig and passing `--env=buildnumber=123` to oc start-build? I get `error: build error: API error (500): {"message":"invalid tag format"}`